# Open with "Wine Internet Explorer" option left in Shutter after removing Wine

Tags: gnome, wine, uninstall, shutter

I installed the latest dev or stable version (I don't remember which now) of Wine using their official repository but then didn't need it any more so removed it, but now I have found that strangely enough when I open Shutter there is an option to open images which wasn't there before which says `Wine Internet Explorer`, what is this option? Is this still installed on my machine? How do I remove it or the option if it's already gone? Clicking the option doesn't seem to do anything. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

This what I mean (I have put a black box over some information I do not want the internet to see):

[image: Wine Internet Explorer option in Shutter]

And this is the output in Terminal I get when clicking that option:

```
GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 938 was not found when attempting to remove it at /usr/bin/shutter line 7247.
env: wine: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually edit `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and remove any lines with `wine`.  I noticed that installing a package may add lines to the file, but uninstalling it will not update this file. It would be too risky, I guess.

Also, cd to `~/.local/share/mime`, and remove all occurrences of `wine`: find and delete lots of files called `x-wine...`, and remove lines from `types` that contain `wine`.
Then, run `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime`.

Comment: The contents of that directory is `jhbuild.desktop              wine-extension-jpe.desktop
jpeg-wrapper.desktop         wine-extension-msp.desktop
mimeinfo.cache               wine-extension-png.desktop
wine-extension-chm.desktop   wine-extension-rtf.desktop
wine-extension-gif.desktop   wine-extension-txt.desktop
wine-extension-hlp.desktop   wine-extension-url.desktop
wine-extension-htm.desktop   wine-extension-vbs.desktop
wine-extension-html.desktop  wine-extension-wri.desktop
wine-extension-ini.desktop   wine-extension-xml.desktop
wine-extension-jfif.desktop`.

Comment: But there is no `mimeapps.list` file.

Comment: Should I just remove all those `wine` files?

Comment: I did some more cleaning up on my system, and edited the answer.

Comment: I have followed what you said but the option in Shutter is still there, so are the desktop files I mentioned above, should I delete the Wine ones?

Comment: Some of them look like they mention that browser...

Comment: I've tried removing the desktop files I mentioned, but still the option remains, is there anywhere else where this data could be being stored?